# Def getdimensions(dimension)

Tags: python

I’m in a python programming class and I have to take the above function and complete it to find the area of a rectangle of 50 by 40. It wants the expected results of 2000 returned not print. Please help.

Comment: What above function? And what question are you even trying to ask? "Please help" is not a question, and it doesn't tell us what sort of information you expect us to provide.

Answer (score -1):

```
def getdimensions(dimension):
    return dimension[0] * dimension[1]
```

Then,

```
>>> result = getdimensions((50, 40))
>>> print(result)
2000
```